# Mosaico menu items missing

Tags: menu, mosaico

We recently installed Mosaico (and Shoreditch Theme and FlexMailer) on our CiviCRM 5.4 Wordpress installation.

None of the required Mosaico menu items are showing up under Mailings or Administer>CiviMail

I've cleared caches, etc.

Thoughts?

Comment: CMS permissions?

Answer (score 1):

Which version of mosaico did you use, because I had the same issue with mosaico 1.1 (described as stable on  https://civicrm.org/extensions/email-template-builder), but actually it is not supported anymore and you should go with the 2.x releases.

Comment: Thanks - I was using 2.0 Beta 3 at the time. I tried other versions, but encountered other problems.

Comment: and did you get it working or not?

Comment: I was able to install the latest development version 2.0-beta4.1528762072 on a test Civi instance of our website. On the surface, it looks correct, but am reluctant to plop this down on less-tech-savvy staff without really knowing this is OK. Btw, I installed via "cv dl --dev flexmailer shoreditch mosaico" per the README.md. Clean and simple. The question is: does anyone know how reliable it is? If there is a different beta version, what would be the "cv" command to get that (excuse me as I'm a relative newbie installing extensions manually via git)